# asp.net mvc data logic structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a bunch of entity models.

Lots of controllers and views and the controllers often go and do a linq query and making it available to the view.

However lets say I have a model Users

and I have a linq query to get all active users

Putting that in a controller might be fine if its done once, but I want to repeat it, im wondering where the correct place to be putting Model specific queries.

Ideally the controller then says Users.getActiveUsers() or similar.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the [repository pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx). Then you have an `IRepository<EntityType>` with a `IQueryable<T> Get(System.Func<T, Boolean> Query)` method... `UserRepo.Get(u=>u.Username == "Bob")`

Comment: Generally, that type of operation should be handled at the as a function of the model or in a repository. I generally lean towards the repository pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the Repository Pattern.

The Repository Pattern allows you to abstract this database logic and reduce the redundancy of common data calls. Since you are formulating LINQ queries often, why not put them into a one common class?

```
public class UserRepository 
{
     private readonly _dbContext MyDbContext;

     public IEnumerable<User> getActiveUsers() 
     {
          // whatever you do to find the active users
          return _dbContext.Where(user => user.Active == true);
     }
}
```

Now you can inject this repository into your controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     private readonly UserRepository _userRepo;

     public HomeController()
     {
         _userRepo = new UserRepository();
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          var activeUsers = _userRepo.getActiveUsers();
          return View(activeUsers);
     }
}
```

The above implementation will solve your problem, but it does tightly couple your controller to your repository. The solution to decouple them would be to use an interface for the UserRepository and then use Dependency Injection (with Ninject, Unity, AutoFaq or whatever) to resolve the type for the interface.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to move data-access logic to separate classes ([repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)) which will act as in-memory collections of entities and hide all data-access logic. E.g. if you have entity `User` you can create repository which will encapsulate all linq queries related to users:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private YourDbContext _db;     

    public UserRepository(YourDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public User GetById(int id)
    {
        return _db.Users.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
    {
        return _db.Users.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsersByRole(string role)
    {
        return _db.Users.Where(u => u.Role == role).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

That will keep all data-access code in one place, without duplications. When you will add another repositories you will find some duplicated logic (e.g. getting entity by id, or getting all entities) which can be moved to base [generic repository](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640294/Learning-MVC-Part-6-Generic-Repository-Pattern-in) class.

I also suggest to depend on repository interface in your controllers:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<User> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<User> GetUsersByRole(string role);
}
```

That will make unit-testing of controllers very easy (mocking repositories and injecting mocks):

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Note: usually you should not use entities in view 
        // create appropriate view models and map entities to them
        var model = _userRepository.GetAll();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: If all your entities inherit from a common class, you can make a generic repository (and interface) with no code re-use. In my case, I put the `Id` field in the base class meaning it can be used for entity-agnostic purposes.

Comment: @Basic I often end with base Entity class, but not always. If you have entities with different type of identity field (int, long, guid) or even composite identities then base class will not help you

Comment: Very true. I was just pointing out a possible win for the OP but you're right, it definitely doesn't suit every situation.